# Python API for creating guitar sheet music

Tags: python, music-sheet

I'm looking for an API for creating music scores, specifically for guitar. The important aspect is that I am able to have formal score style music as well as the less formal guitar tablature. I would prefer Python, but any language will do.

Does such a package exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/) is a sheet music typesetting or "engraving" tool that supports producing sheet music in both formal score & guitar tablature *(it even supports Gregorian chant notation)*.

There are several python libraries that can interact with Lilypond listed on [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=lilypond) and Lilypond has its own API or can be invoked with text input.